# Display fillable PDF in webpage with submit button that emails completed form

Tags: jquery, forms, pdf, embed

Would it be possible, using only HTML, CSS and/or jQuery, to embed a fillable PDF into a webpage as itself a form with a submit button? Upon submission, the finished PDF would be sent to the email of the site admin.

Comment: I think that you'd need at least a server with php or asp or whatsoever which could get the data from the form, process it and send it back. Maybe it can be done with jQuery on the client side but I'm not sure about it. There are some php libraries that can create a pdf (fpdf, pdflib...)

Comment: I think you'd need something like [SelectPDF](http://selectpdf.com/) on the backend to do something like that -- likely just make a normal HTML form and convert the results into a PDF using the .NET library linked and e-mail it from there. Though you may have some luck with something such as [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

Comment: And how do you plan to embed a PDF in a web page that works across all browsers? Or do you not need that?

Answer (score 0):

You would add the submit button to the PDF itself.

However, you have to be aware that, in particular, the PDF viewers coming with the web browsers are too dumb to understand Actions, and even more so, JavaScript.

If Adobe Reader is used to view and fill the form, in order to send back the completed form as a PDF attachment, Reader XI or newer is necessary.